# Is this stackable low RPM generator design viable?

Tags: design, electromagnetism, generator, inductance

I'm trying to invent viable hand-crank energy generator for charging phones and similar low-power appliances. I want to avoid gears altogether in the design, because they are hard to manufacture at home and because I don't want to lose any of the already small power generated by hand to friction between gears. With a single axis device, there is almost no friction or wear.

The concept looks like this:

[image]

This is what it would look tiled. The idea here is that you can tile it indefinitely, the only limit is your own strength (and patience when putting it together).

[image]

The magnets will be neodymium magnets. There's intentionally six of them but only five coils - this aims to reduce the "zero point" strength - the most stable point of attraction between coil cores and magnets.

The coils would have ferrite cores and each would have its own rectifier.

The magnets will be altered in polarity so that two opposing magnets will always be attracted to each other and therefore exert maximum possible field over the coil.

Questions:

- Is this a good design for low RPM (40-100 RMP)?
- What would be the ideal number of turns if the target voltage is 5V, given the aforementioned RPM?
- Are ferrite cores good idea? Or should I use iron or air cored coils instead?

Comment: Do you intentionally avoid employing gears? Most similar devices use a reduction gearing to turn the slow hand cranking action into a much faster rotation on the generator

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that. Gears mean power loss to friction and durability loss due to wear. Single axis device is pretty eternal compared to geared one.

Comment: A normal gear is incredibly efficient, and it would bring more than it takes, and also you can buy them off the shelf, no need to manufacture. Otherwise seems like trying to reinvent the wheel. In your design the % of rotation that a magnet is in front of a coil is like 50%, which will also limit a lot efficiency. As you iterate with your design you'll converge to a modern motor

Comment: Hand crank generator to charge a phone battery-not bad, if you can do it - I mean the charging. A smallish battery has 2000mAh at 4V. It's about 29kJ energy. That's equivalent with lifting 100kg mass to 29,5 meter altitude or 60 times a 0,5m lift. Or only 10kg 600 times 0,5m, with a hand. Congratulations! BTW have you done any calculations how wide magnetic flux variation you can achieve in one coil?

Comment: Looking at the above figures another way: 29 kJ if delivered in 1 hour would require 8 W continuous without friction, resistive and conversion losses. That's probably difficult to sustain by hand especially if the unit is hand-held. For reference a normal adult should be capable of sustaining 150 W when cycling. That works out close to 1 kWh over 8 hours.

Comment: Given a specific mass of magnet and copper, you can generate more power by spinning it faster. At  low rpm, let's say 1/100 the practical speed, you would need to stack 100 generators in series to achieve the same voltage; increasing the copper loss 100 fold. I suspect you'll find the "inefficient" gears are actually more efficient.

Comment: To add to what Brian said, most motors/generators are good for low torque and high RPM. Whereas human hand is best for high torque and low speed. You can either resolve this discrepancy by gearing, or by a very different motor design, like a stepper motor. Your design already looks somewhat reminiscent to a stepper - you may want to read more on them for additional inspiration :)

Comment: please let go of it. this wouldn't work as a practical device.

Comment: These devices already exist commercially as a hand cranked gearbox and dynamo for emergency flashlight and emergency phone charging.  They can include a solar panel and battery.  Bear in mind in an emergency you don't necessarily need a full charge.  It is likely that he came across some of the [already accepted and ubiquitous designs](https://www.amazon.com/Emergency-MECO-Weather-Flashlight-Survival/dp/B01M0PXCSP/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1532996896&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=dynamo+phone+charger&psc=1) and wanted to improve them.

Comment: I've spent time looking for low RPM DC motors or generators for small air or water turbines, and the market is pretty barren, and I think this is partly because of other effects mentioned in these comments, and partly because at low RPM you need many hair thin windings with many many many turns, likely complicating manufacture.  So far I've made one with rare earth magnets, the core of an old hobby motor, a steel casing and endcaps milled on a lathe, 8 axial windings of 50 turns each 22guage magnet wire.  turning it in the hand it can barely light a board of 12 15mA LEDs,

Comment: And in the lathe at 800 to 1000 RPM it'll put out about 5v 1A.  I'm not familiar with disc designs myself.  I used an axial design because of readily salvageable silicon steel cores.